# How to prove that an integer linear program is infeasible?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming, discrete-optimization, reference-works

I have an ILP which I would like to show as infeasible. The naive idea I had was to try to show that the relaxed LP is also infeasible. Unfortunately, I know that the LP is feasible.

I want to know if there are any generic methods or conditions I can check for proving that an ILP is infeasible.

I would really appreciate if you can point to some reference material. I tried to Google for this, but couldn't get something which I could work with.

Comment: What exact ILP do you have?

Comment: Let the MIP solver tell you the model is integer infeasible (this may take a while depending on the model). This should be rigorous (except for numerical issues).

Comment: If you let your MIP solver use cuts only (without branch&bound, which may take considerably longer than with b&b), and if you let it log the cuts that it adds, you have reproducible proof.

Comment: I was trying to use Mathematica to check if the ILP was feasible. I also know that if I do the calculations upto some approximation, then ILP is feasible(Initially tried with Matlab). The problem is my ILP is large(around 300 variables, but the ILP has a structure), that Mathematica couldn't even give a trivial feasible solution in case of relaxed LP. 

Can you suggest MIP solver which doesn't solve using approximations. I never used them before, so I am not sure which one to use.

Comment: 300 variables is considered small. If you have access to a state of the art MIP solver such as Cplex or Gurobi, this should solve (almost surely)  very fast. Matlabs or Mathematicas MIP solver is good for smaller or easier problems but does not really compete with the solvers I mentioned.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen I checked Gurobi. As i understand it, it is a library which can be imported into python or other softwares which then be used to solve the MIP. As i said in the previous comment that I am interested in solver which doesn't use approximations. For example I have constraint \sum_i x_i=0. If I take the approximations and solve the MIP with constraint \sum_i x_i<\epsilon, then I know that the MIP is feasible(This can be shown easily for my problem.).

Comment: I am not sure what you precisely mean by approximations, but I would claim Gurobi is not using approximations. Of course it is using floating point computations, and there are some tolerances involved.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen I meant the floating point computations. Due to tolerances, \sum x_i < 10^-9 (or some other number) is considered the same as \sum x_i =0. But for my problem, I know that these two cases are different (can be argued analytically based on the structure).

Comment: There are rational LP and MIP solvers for such "crazy" models.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46953/discussion-between-phani-raj-and-erwin-kalvelagen).

Comment: Sorry I was not available to do that

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen Do you have recommendations regarding solvers? I was trying SCIP, but couldn't install it.

Comment: Sorry, I never had the need to use a rational LP or MIP solver.